# Linear operators $T: X \rightarrow Y$ for which $\dim (\operatorname{Im}(T)) \succ \dim(X)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

> **Theorem:** Let $X, Y$ be $\mathbb{k}$-vector spaces, and
> $T: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator. Then, if $\dim(X)$ is finite,
> $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T)) \preceq \dim(X)$.

I'm looking for examples where $\dim(X)= \infty$, and $\dim (\operatorname{Im}(T)) \succ \dim(X)$.

Edit: Is this result true for infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: The image of any basis of $X$ generates all of $\operatorname{Im}(T).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was thinking that. Then, what is the value of the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is always true, even in the infinite-dimensional setting.

Indeed, if $\{e_i: i \in I\}$ is a basis of $X$, then $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \operatorname{span}\{Te_i: i \in I\}$ which shows that $\dim \operatorname{Im(T)}\le |I| = \dim(X)$.

Alternatively, by the first isomorphism theorem
$$\operatorname{Im}(T) \cong X/\ker T$$
and thus $$\dim \operatorname{Im}(T) = \dim X/\ker T \leq \dim X.$$
This inequality can be strict: take $X$ your favorite vector space of dimension $n \geq 2$ (infinite dimension is also allowed) and consider any linear map
$$T: X \to \mathbb{k}.$$